# How to make it so that when you click on a dynamic cell, its contents (text and numbers) are written to the array?

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, uitableview

There is a table with data. I want when a user clicks on any of the cells the data (there are labels with strings and numbers) from this cell are written to the array.

Comment: Override `didSelectRow`, and update your array with the info?

Comment: yes i am using `didSelectRowAt` I don’t understand how to read the data from the label and add it to the array

Answer (score 0):

in order to do this task you have to initialize an array and in table view functions which "didSelectRowAt" append the value of the label text into that array. for example:

- first, initialize an array.

var Array = String

- go to the function of table view "didSelectRowAt".

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

Array.append(cell.label.text)

}